# Combining Multiple CSVs in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to combine hundreds of CSVs together in python using the following code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = '/Users/parkerbolstad/Downloads/'

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files)
df_merged   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
df_merged.to_csv( "merged.csv")
```

But, this combines all the files together in totality. The first column of each file is dates. I want to pull the dates from the first file and then skip them for the rest.

As of now, I have a new column with dates in it every 4 columns.

Comment: you could show example data and expected result. There are other methods to combine dataframes and it documentation should be special page about it.

Comment: maybe you should convert column dates into `index` and then it will use index to combine data

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `for`-loop to remove this column in all `df` except first - `[1:]`

```
for df in df_from_each_file[1:]:
    df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021.08.01', '2021.08.02', '2021.08.03'],
    'value': ['A', 'B', 'C']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021.08.01', '2021.08.02', '2021.08.03'],
    'value': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021.08.01', '2021.08.02', '2021.08.03'],
    'value': ['1', '2', '3']
})

df_from_each_file = [df1, df2, df3]

for df in df_from_each_file[1:]:
    df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)

result = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1) 

print(result)
```

Result:

```
         date value value value
0  2021.08.01     A     X     1
1  2021.08.02     B     Y     2
2  2021.08.03     C     Z     3
```

---

Or in all `df` convert column with `date` into `index` and later reset index.

This should correctly connect rows if dates will be in different rows or there will be missing dates.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021.08.01', '2021.08.02', '2021.08.03'],
    'value': ['A', 'B', 'C']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021.08.01', '2021.08.02', '2021.08.03'],
    'value': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021.08.01', '2021.08.02', '2021.08.03'],
    'value': ['1', '2', '3']
})

df_from_each_file = [df1, df2, df3]

for df in df_from_each_file:
    df.index = df['date']
    df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)

result = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1)
#result = result.sort_index()
result = result.reset_index()

print(result)
```